# Text Not Colored Anymore And Autocompletion Not Working Anymore In Xcode ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

Code text in ViewController.swift in Xcode is suddenly not colored anymore (keywords, objects, etc.) except for types like string and int. Also autocompletion is not working anymore. Any other swift file within the same project, like AppDelegate for example is still fine, i.e. colored. Simulation of my project is also still working. I am using Xcode 12.4, macOS 10.15.7. It's only happening with this specific project I'm working on, all my other projects are still ok. Restarting Xcode/rebooting the computer didn't help. Any help is very appreciated, thanks!
[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: Try to restart Xcode, or your computer

Comment: Thanks, I did that already with no success.

Comment: Try to run `Cmd + Shift + K` to clean the build folder. Sometimes Xcode has some issues with cached content and this helps. It might take some time to regenerate the things, but maybe it starts working again after a minute or so

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the Derived Data folder and then restarting your Mac.

click - Command and then , key

Go to Locations>Derived Data and delete the folder

Answer (score 0):

Update: Clearing the folder Derived Data and cleaning the build folder didn't help, so I deleted "ViewController.swift" after copying the code and then pasted that code into a newly created file "ViewController". Seemed to be a bit of a "nuclear option" to me, especially since I still don't know, why this happened in the first place. But it did the trick.